# Tableview cell does not cover the whole area as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been googling an answer for this for hours but cannot find anything that actually works in my case and I've no idea why.

I'm creating a tableview which should be from the top of the tableview to the bottom of the tableview, but in this case it doesn't.

[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cljD.png)
In this image you can see how it looks like in the storyboard (Which is also the way I want it to look like), you can see it almost cover the whole tableview.

And this is the result:
[result of tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Hp4.png)

I'm trying to make the tableview cell start from the top and contain all the way to the bottom of the tableview (Well, like the storyboard image)

I've added this...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 410
}
```

Comment: why are you using tableview when there's only one cell? for if you were using stackview (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) in your case, you wouldn't need to do anything else, it just would do what you expect.

Comment: So, maybe I should add them separately? Into more cells? @KirilS.

Comment: but why tableview at all? tableview is mostly for serializing data of the same or similar type. Here you have a one single form. What problem are you trying to solve using tableview?

Comment: @KirilS. I’m using it to make them in a perfect line and make a scrollview.

Comment: @KirilS. The problem i’m trying to solve is: i’ll create similar forms (to the one in the picture) and instead of adding more tableviews and viewcontrollers. I considering using 1 and just change label data

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use UITableView

You add vertical scrollview and add one contianer UIView in it then you can add mutiple UILable and UITextField one bellow another.

Comment: Alright. But my idea was to use this tableview for other forms. (I’ll add similar forms, but ill change the text) still recommend to not use tableview?

Comment: You can copy paste Container view and created multiple forms with less efforts. its easy for maintain also